# Как правильно сделать разное поведение одного объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру на подобии Phasmaphobia и у меня есть призрак, который как и в оригинальной игре может быть разных типов (разная скорость, разные улики, разная активность, разные действия). То есть разная логика в зависимости от типа призрака, который выбирается случайно в начале игры. Как это сделать правильно, чтобы не городить все возможные варианты в одном классе, т.к. с этим невозможно работать?

Comment: Для этого придумали ООП. Придумайте все типы призраков и их способности. Все общие способности, параметры оставьте в базовом классе к примеру `GhostBase`, а от него уже наследуете каждый тип призрака, который переопределяет базовую скорость и когда он нападает на игрока, а также добавляет свои уникальные способности. https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.7.php

Comment: То есть, в идеале должен быть префаб на каждый производный класс, чтобы потом спавнить случайно один из них?

Comment: Верно. Вы попробуйте придумать несколько уникальных призраков, а не сразу 20+ как в фазме. Будет намного легче и сразу разберетесь со всей этой системой классов.

Comment: понял, спасибо.